# How to make gnome-shell only using one specified GPU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 22.04, graphics

I have this `nvidia-smi` output:

```
Fri Feb 23 08:24:55 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.154.05             Driver Version: 535.154.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti     Off | 00000000:A1:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8               4W / 300W |    332MiB / 11264MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A10                     Off | 00000000:C1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   37C    P8              11W / 150W |     11MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1773    C+G   ...libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon      156MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1834      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        169MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      1834      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          3MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expect I can just use one GPU for `PID 1834` which is `gnome-shell` which is using RTX series instead of A10, therefore expected nvidia-smi output will be like this:

```
Fri Feb 23 08:24:55 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.154.05             Driver Version: 535.154.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti     Off | 00000000:A1:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8               4W / 300W |    332MiB / 11264MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A10                     Off | 00000000:C1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   37C    P8              11W / 150W |     0MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1773    C+G   ...libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon      156MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1834      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        169MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I do that?